# Segmentation fault error while running pyspark in Apache Spark 2.4.7

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, segmentation-fault, python-3.7, spark2

Getting **Segmentation fault** error while running */opt/spark2/bin/pyspark --master yarn --conf spark.ui.port=0* in Kali Linux.

I verified Python3.7 is under /usr/bin and spark can access it. While running */opt/spark2/bin/spark-shell --master yarn --conf spark.ui.port=0*, spark-shell appears correctly. But with pyspark,python is coming but it is showing **Segmentation fault** and stops executing immediately. It should start the shell. Please help me to overcome the issue.

Comment: I downgraded python to 3.6.9 and it's working fine.